# Should I click on a dashboard graph and what should happen?

Tags: graphs

I have been wondering about a simple behavior around a dashboard graph:

Should I click on the graph?

If so, what should be the most effective action to take:

a) Open a table with graph data
b) Drill down to a another graph with more detailed information
c) Open a zoom window to detail a specific time interval

What would be the common sense regarding graph interaction? Should have graph interaction at all?

Comment: This can be a really good question, but I think it will need more context to understand the use case. 

Are there additional, related graphs on the page? 
What kind of graphs are you working with? 
Do you have a screen of the surrounding UI? 
What other interactions is the data used for? 
Is the dashboard part of a larger component? 
Will the user need to be able to "undo" whatever action is taken after the click?

Answer (score 2):

The most common interactions with graphs from my experience is to show more details on mouse over.

3 different examples showing the same behaviour:

[image]

[image]

[image]

The other interactions that you described are good but you need to consider the user experience. Keep that in mind when creating.